# Как изменить css по названию документа?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Возможо ли изменить css по названию документа, например:

```
index.html a {color:orange;}
```

или

```
$('index.html a').css({'color':'orange'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
var test = document.getElementById("test");
 if(s.dataset.file == "index.html"){
  test.style.color = "red";
 } else {
  test.innerText ="Что-то не работает этот скрипт";
 }
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title data-file="index.html">Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">Test</div>
</body>
```

Вообщем, логика такова: нужно как-то пометить нужную страницу. Я это сделал, добавив в тег `title` дополнительный атрибут с названием файла.

Answer (score 0):

Через CSS нельзя (не существует такого селектора), а через JS - легко:

1. Получаете часть URL после имени хоста, через `document.location.pathname`;
2. Проверяете наличие вашего паттерна в `pathname`, используя любой удобный метод проверки вхождения подстроки;
3. Применяете стили (через инжект CSS-файла / созданием элемента `<style>` / через свойство `style` для отдельных элементов).

Простой пример:

```js
let test = document.getElementById('test'),
    pageName = document.location.pathname;
console.log('pageName (у здешних вставок кода оно всегда "/js"): ' + pageName);


test.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // это условие вернет false (т.к. в пути не содержится 'search') и стиль применен не будет
  if(pageName.indexOf('search') !== -1)
    test.style.borderRadius = '50px'; 

  // а тут условие выполняется, и фоновый цвет изменится на зеленый
  if(pageName.indexOf('js') !== -1)
    test.style.backgroundColor = '#4a4';
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
Кликните по элементу для применения стилей
<div id="test"></div>
```

Когда требуется гибкость, вместо `indexOf` (который тут использован для простоты) при сравнении можно использовать регулярное выражение, например `/^\/articles\/[\w-]+?.php/i`.